# Is it possible to create only one filter in the saved filters area sidebar?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, custom-questions-list

I saw this new area in the sidebar:

[image: SS]

After creating a filter:

[image: SS1]

I noticed that I'm only able to delete or edit it, not create a new one

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Related: [Custom question lists April status update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327816/363946).

Comment: Ah I just found in that question's answers [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328000/363946), and that user also includes the work around to add more, with a  request for the button to stay or an edit button to be added.

Comment: ya noticed that that too, but no comments there, so let's see what happens here for now :)

Comment: You can, of course, create additional filters using the _filter_ button at the top of the page and then using _save filter_. Still, an odd UX choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Erik A in the comments to the question, it is possible to have more than one custom filter, however (and again as @Erik A mentioned) is an odd UX choice the way to do it.

Steps to create a second(or more) custom filter:

1. Hit the Edit filter icon (which leads to the filter section with current options selected)
2. Choose the options you want to your new filter
3. Hit Save filter button (here comes the odd UX choice)
4. Now you're prompt to choose whether you want to apply the options to the current filter (which means EDIT), or create a new filter.